# java.io.FileNotFoundException: WebContent\WEB-INF\classes\nmdp.json (The system cannot find the path specified)

Tags: json, eclipse, tomcat, web-applications, web

```
   try {
                InputStream fis = new FileInputStream("WebContent/WEB-INF/classes/nmdp.json");
                JsonReader jsonReader =Json.createReader(fis);


                //JsonObject from jsonReader
                JsonObject jsonObject = jsonReader.readObject();

                JDBC_DRIVER = jsonObject.getString("JDBC_DRIVER");
                DB_URL = jsonObject.getString("DB_URL");
                USER = jsonObject.getString("USER");
                PASSWORD = jsonObject.getString("PASSWORD");

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

I am able to access this file from main function.. But in the case of java web application.. i am getting this exception....

Comment: Use your file path other than WEB-INF.

Comment: I placed file in root of the Project. But still same :-(

Comment: I am able to access by using absolute path.. But my requirement is access the file using relative path..Please help..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the file is in you classpath load it as a resource:

```
InputStream in = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/nmdp.json");
```

1. The WebContent directory is a placeholder in Eclipse to store your projects resources. When deployed, this will be the root of your app, therefore calling "/WebContent/..." will only work in Eclipse.
2. Reading a file with FileInputStream will only work, if your war file was unpacked within the server.